# java.lang.NullPointerException in 'boolean java.io.File.exists()'

Tags: android

when iam trying to get the downloaded photo frame from external storage i am getting this error like NullPointerException in this line **file.exists()**.

I am getting error in android 6 devices..
And the code snippet i wrote is as follows..

In the above snippet fp represents file for pip photo frame and fp1 represents file for pip mask

if ((fp.exists() && (fp1.exists()))) {

if ((path_downloaded != null) && (path_downloaded2 != null)) {

```
                download_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + path_downloaded + "/output" + frame_pos + ".png");
                download_bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + path_downloaded2 + "/output" + frame_pos + ".png");
                if ((download_bitmap != null) && (download_bitmap2 != null)) {
                    frameBitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(download_bitmap, width, height, false);
                    maskBitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(download_bitmap2, width, height, false);

                    if ((frameBitmap1 != null) && (maskBitmap1 != null)) {
                       //functionality related code
                    }
                    //  showLoadedAd();
                }
            }
```

Comment: In the above snippet fp represents file for pip photo frame and fp1 represents file for pip mask

Comment: Please put that info in your post to begin with. Further your post is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` no longer works as of Android 11, and only works in Android 10 if you set a special flag in AndroidManifest. Read up about Scoped Storage here:

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

Comment: actually am getting this error in android 6 devices

Comment: do you have access to read/write external storage? I mean, did you set that permission on your app?